# Angular 2 How do get mouseX on setInterval with Observables?

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I get the current mouse position in an setInterval. How can I accomplish the same with Typescript and Angular 2?

I mean I can create a timer with Observables, but how can I read the current mouse Position within that timer?

```
let startX = event.pageX;

setInterval(function(){
    let diff = window.mouseX - startX;
    console.log(diff);
}, 50)
```

Comment: The exact same way? What's the problem? And what makes you think you can't use setInterval() with Angular or TypeScript?

Comment: First, you should create an observable.

Comment: @JB Nizet Because I can't access the window Object in that way. It's not known by Typescript

Comment: @Roman C Which one?

Comment: @TrevorHector I'm not sure what are you asking.

Comment: Then your typescript project is not configured correctly. If TypeScript could not use the window object, it would be pretty useless to write applications running in the browser. Make sure you have "dom", in the compilerOptions.lib property of your tsconfig.json. And tell us precisely what happens when trying to use setInterval and window from one of your ts files.

Comment: if you can create a plunker?

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for your help. The attribute was simply not available on window. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
    let startX = event.pageX;


   let observable =  Observable.create( (observer: any) => {

        setInterval(function(){
          let diff = window.mouseX - startX;
          observer.next(diff);
       }, 50)

    });
```